# "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'" error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am new to asp.net programming

I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'

near

```
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is my complete code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserClass uc,HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

    string sqlquery = "insert into [dbo].[MVCregUser] (Uname, Uemail, Upwd, Gender, Uimage) values (@Uname, @Uemail, @Upwd, @Gender, @Uimage,)";
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);

    sqlconn.Open();

    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname",uc.Uname);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uemail", uc.Uemail);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Upwd", uc.Upwd);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", uc.Gender);

    if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string imgpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~//User-Images"), filename);
        file.SaveAs(imgpath);
    }

    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uimage", "~//User-Images"+file.FileName);

    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlconn.Close();

    ViewData["Message"] = "User Record " + uc.Uname + " Is Saved Successfully";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: remove last , in values

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 4):

On this line:

```
string sqlquery = "insert into [dbo].[MVCregUser] (Uname,Uemail,Upwd,Gender,Uimage) values (@Uname,@Uemail,@Upwd,@Gender,@Uimage,)";
```

The comma in the end is beaking SQL Syntax. Please remove it and try again like this:

```
string sqlquery = "insert into [dbo].[MVCregUser] (Uname,Uemail,Upwd,Gender,Uimage) values (@Uname,@Uemail,@Upwd,@Gender,@Uimage)";
```